# Index was outside the bounds of the array. // Array with AudioSource

Tags: arrays, list, range

I'm learning to code along with unity for the past 1.5month and I cannot get this problem resolved. I've tried looking it up several times and cannot get the answer that I need. I know it probably be a simple fix for everyone but for me - its not... i'm not good with Arrays.

I'm trying to make a script that going to handle my sounds but I keep getting this error. Here's the script;

```
public AudioSource[] mySounds;

public AudioSource fire;
public AudioSource reload;
public AudioSource zombieDeath;




void Start()
{
    mySounds = GetComponents<AudioSource>();

    fire = mySounds[0];
    reload = mySounds[1];                           //  <----  line 22.
    zombieDeath = mySounds[2];
}

public void PlayFire()
{
    fire.Play();
}

public void PlayReload()
{
    reload.Play();
}

public void PlayZombieDeath()
{
    zombieDeath.Play();
}
```

And I keep getting the error in unity on line 22. I could use some help..

Comment: If you get an error, always include the error-message you are getting, so that we can help you. If I had to guess, mySounds has only one element, so index 1 is empty?

Comment: Are you sure that you have 3 AudioSources components in the object that has the script? Can you print the size of mySounds like so: `print(mySounds.length.toString());` just after `mySounds = GetComponents<AudioSource>();` please and show us the result?